# Post con spring boot SQL server

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, post

Estoy tratando de guardar datos desde spring boot a una base de datos de sql server, los metodos GET funcionan correctamente, pero el POST, en PostMan me da el error 404.
los codigos son los siguientes:

el repositorio es asi:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.guardias.backend.modelo.Persona;

@Repository
public interface IPersonaRepositorio extends JpaRepository<Persona, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select * from persona where id_persona = :idPersona", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Persona> getPersonaById(Long idPersona);
}
```

Luego tengo el servicio que es de la siguiente manera:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.guardias.backend.modelo.Persona;
import com.guardias.backend.repositorio.IPersonaRepositorio;

@Service
public class PersonaServicio {

    @Autowired
    private IPersonaRepositorio PersonaRepositorio;

    public List<Persona> findAll() {
        return PersonaRepositorio.findAll();
    }

    public List<Persona> getPersonaById(long Id) {
        return PersonaRepositorio.getPersonaById(Id);
    }

    public <S extends Persona> S save(S entity) {
        return PersonaRepositorio.save(entity);
    }
}
```

y por ultimo tengo el controlador de la siguiente manera:

```
package com.guardias.backend.controlador;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.guardias.backend.modelo.Persona;
import com.guardias.backend.servicio.PersonaServicio;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/V1/")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class PersonaControlador {

    @Autowired
    private PersonaServicio personaServicio;

    @GetMapping("/listaPersonas")
    private ResponseEntity<List<Persona>> getAllPersonas() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(personaServicio.findAll());
    }

    @GetMapping("/PersonaId")
    public List<Persona> personaById() {
        return personaServicio.getPersonaById((long) 15);
    }

    @PostMapping
    private ResponseEntity<Persona> savePersona(@RequestBody Persona persona) {
        try {
            Persona personaGuardada = personaServicio.save(persona);
            return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/personas/" + personaGuardada.getIdPersona())).body(personaGuardada);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }
    }
}
```

ademas tengo una clase Modelo de Persona con sus constructores, sus Getters y Setters y las anotaciones para que se corresponda con los campos de la base de datos. Como les dije anteriormente, traer el listado desde la base de datos y mostrarlos en postman si funciona correctamente.